# UIDocumentInteractionController not appearing on iPad but working on iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to display a `UIDocumentInteractionController` on my app. Everything is working perfectly on iPhone, but nothing is happening on iPad. Here is my code:

```
    interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageFile];
    interactionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    interactionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self commentForInstagram] forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

`interactionController` is a strong reference to an instance, and `imageFile` exists. On iPhone, it brings up the 'Open With..' dialog and Instagram is present. On iPad, absolutely nothing happens when the above code runs. Yes, I do have Instagram installed and working on my iPad.

What could be the reason that nothing is happening when the code is executed? `self.view` and `self.view.frame` are valid objects (tested on debug).

Thanks, Can.

Comment: What is the return value when you call `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`? Are you sure that `imageFile` is not `nil` and is a valid file URL pointing to an image file?

Comment: as I've stated clearly in the question, imageFile exists. the problem seems to be originating from the present method and how it behaves differently on iPhone and iPad. if i pass in a custom rect, and self.view.windows as the view, it does seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

On iPad UIDocumentInteractionController appearing like Pop Up 
Try something like this:

```
-(void)shareClick:(UIButton*)sender {
   /*some code*/
   CGRect rectForAppearing = [sender.superview convertRect:sender.frame toView:self.view];
   [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For iPad you have to meet these 2 things:

1. Define area for DocumentActionMenu

   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
2. **Use iPad**, not simulator

Comment: Thanks. FYI can use CGRectZero instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Use `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`.

For example, if you want the menu to be presented from the bottom, try

```
[interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier today.

First of all, do not pass the `frame` of your view to `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated`. The given rect is supposed to be in the coordinates of the view. The `frame` of the view is in the coordinates of the view's superview.

On iPhone, passing the `bounds` of the view worked, but on iPad, Xcode (7.2.1) would complain about unsatisfiable constraints and not display the document interaction controller's view (DIC).

Instead of the `bounds`, I tried to pass `CGRectZero` as the first parameter which anchors the DIC in the upper left corner of the view. This works but it looks bad.

In order to position the DIC at the center of the bottom edge of the view, you can specify a rect of size `CGSizeZero` positioned at the center of the bottom edge of the view (use the view's `bounds` to compute the position). This works and looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

`presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:` - This is talking about where the popover *arrow* points.

The view is the view that the arrow points at, and the rect is the rect *inside the view* that the arrow points at.

Once you understand that this is easy.

```
- (void)shareClick:(UIButton*)sender
{
   /*some code*/
   [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:sender.bounds inView:sender animated:YES];
}
```

So now the arrow will point to an edge of the bounds of the button.

Most of the time this is what you want but you could for example inset this rect to have the arrow point inside the button.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I checked the frame that is being passed and saw that x and y are set to 0. Next I tried to change those values (by keeping width and height as passed) and the popup showed up. Here the code:

```
-(void)openDocument:(UIView*)senderView {

   CGRect rectForAppearing = [senderView convertRect:senderView.frame toView:senderView];

   if (isIPAD)
     rectForAppearing =  CGRectMake(100, 100, rectForAppearing.size.width, rectForAppearing.size.height);

   [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

}

The popup appears on an Ipad in the top right corner. You can of course twist those 100,100 parameters to your desire. On iPhones i leave the popover as is (at the bottom)